# Sumar y agrupar por celda

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo una duda que no logro resolver. Tengo una tabla con 4 columnas:

[image: Tabla]

Las matrículas pueden aparecer varias veces repetidas. 
Necesito hacer que recorra las filas y agrupe (sume) por matrícula el valor de horas y picadas. Pero además necesito que compruebe el pasillo y almacene aquel pasillo donde el valor de horas sea mayor.

Es decir, para la matrícula 12239 debería almacenarse esto:

12239 | M3/M4 | 2080 | 5,96 |

Acepto cualquier tipo de ayuda porque estoy atascadísimo...

Gracias.

Comment: Puedes resumir tus datos con 2 tablas dinámicas. En una obtienes la suma de horas y picadas por matrícula, y en otra puedes obtener el pasillo con valor de horas máximo (1 mejor) por matrícula.

Comment: En la mayoría de los casos la tabla dinámica es por mucho la mejor opción cuando se trata de consolidar datos, en este caso particular quizá no sea lo mejor debido a la estructura de datos que se requiere `12239 | M3/M4 | 2080 | 5,96 |` , claro que hay ocasiones donde hay que optar entre inconvenientes, posiblemente aplique en este caso y se opte por tener otra presentación de la informacion, aunque no estoy del todo seguro si se puede filtrar para mostrar solo el pasillo con mas horas pero que a su vez este relacionado con la matricula en cuestión.

Comment: @NolbertoLopez En una sola tabla dinámica no, no se puede hacer. Por eso dije en 2 tablas dinámicas.

Comment: Entiendo @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes , precisamente por eso digo que en ocasiones se opta entre inconvenientes, quizá para dogwall no sea buena opción tener el resultado en dos tablas, ademas, no lo he probado así que no estoy seguro que en esa otra tabla dinámica se pueda filtrar para mostrar solo el pasillo con mas horas y que a su vez este relacionado con la matricula en cuestión.

Comment: Buenas, efectivamente la opción de manejar dos tablas, en esta ocasión, no es viable. Yo no he podido (o sabido) filtrar la tabla para mostrar el pasillo con más horas.
De todas formas se agradecen los aportes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te puede servir, si como en el ejemplo las matrículas no se repiten más de 2 veces, en otro caso tendría que mirar alguna otra manera:

```
Sub Consolidar()

    Dim Picadas As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Horas As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Pasillos As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim Datos As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Datos = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").UsedRange.Value 'cambia Hoja1 por tu hoja

    'suponiendo que matricula es columna A y total horas columna D
    For i = 2 To UBound(Datos)
        If Not Picadas.Exists(Datos(i, 1)) Then 'horas y picadas
            Picadas.Add Datos(i, 1), Datos(i, 3) 'añadimos las picadas
            Horas.Add Datos(i, 1), Datos(i, 4) 'añadimos las horas
            Pasillos.Add Datos(i, 1), Datos(i, 2) 'añadimos pasillos
        Else
            Picadas(Datos(i, 1)) = Picadas(Datos(i, 1)) + Datos(i, 3) 'sumamos picadas
            'Esto es asumiendo que las amtriculas salen sólo 2 veces por tu ejemplo
            If Horas(Datos(i, 1)) < Datos(i, 4) Then Pasillos(i, 1) = Datos(i, 2)
            Horas(Datos(i, 1)) = Horas(Datos(i, 1)) + Datos(i, 4) 'sumamos horas
        End If
    Next i

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja2") 'esto ponlo donde necesites
        .Range("A1") = "Matricula"
        .Range("B1") = "Pasillo"
        .Range("C1") = "Total Picadas"
        .Range("D1") = "Total Horas"
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(Picadas.Count) = Application.Transpose(Picadas.Keys) 'Matriculas
        .Cells(2, 3).Resize(Picadas.Count) = Application.Transpose(Picadas.Items) 'Picadas
        .Cells(2, 3).Resize(Picadas.Count) = Application.Transpose(Horas.Items) 'Horas
        For i = 2 To Picadas.Count + 1 'Pasillos con más horas
            .Cells(i, 2) = Pasillos(.Cells(i, 1))
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Las matrículas se repiten n veces, puede ser una, dos o más veces. De todas formas tu ejemplo me ha servido como ayuda para montarlo.

Para el item del diccionario he concatenado las celdas necesarias y luego si la clave(matricula) existia en el diccionario hago un split para separar los elementos de la cadena y asignaba los valores pertinentes. Un poco aparatoso pero funcional.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando en cuenta que estas usando Tablas, con formulas seria de la siguiente manera.

Primero tienes que copiar los datos de la columna matricula y pegar en otra hoja, luego usa la opción "`Eliminar duplicados`" del menú "`Datos`" para obtener la lista única de matriculas.

Para obtener el pasillo con mas horas de cada Matricula, usar la siguiente formula matricial.

```
=INDICE(Tabla1[Pasillo],COINCIDIR(MAX(SI(Tabla1[Matricula]=Hoja2!A2,Tabla1[Total Horas])),Tabla1[Total Horas],0))
```

La clave en esta formula es la combinación de las funciones `COINCIDIR, MAX, SI`, con estas se obtiene la posición del pasillo con mas horas pero que a su vez este relacionado con la Matricula en turno, esa posición es la que necesita la función `INDICE` para devolver el dato.

Recuerda que las formulas matriciales se ingresan presionando la combinación de teclas `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER` luego de teclearla o pegarla, las formulas normales se ingresan presionando Enter.

Una vez ingresada la formula, esta se vera con llaves al inicio y final.

```
{=INDICE(Tabla1[Pasillo],COINCIDIR(MAX(SI(Tabla1[Matricula]=Hoja2!A2,Tabla1[Total Horas])),Tabla1[Total Horas],0))}
```

https://support.office.com/es-es/article/crear-una-f%C3%B3rmula-de-matriz-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d

Total Picadas.

```
=SUMAR.SI(Tabla1[Matricula],Hoja2!A2,Tabla1[Total Picadas])
```

Total Horas.

```
=SUMAR.SI(Tabla1[Matricula],Hoja2!A2,Tabla1[Total Horas])
```

Estas dos ultimas formulas son normales ( no matriciales ).